# Does the "intersection property" of a topological basis require proper subset?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Does the intersection property of a basis on a topology require that the induced set is strictly contained in the intersection of the two sets?

By "intersection property," I am referring to the property which states:
If $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for a topology on a set $X$, and $x\in X$ is contained in some $B_1$ and $B_2$ in $\mathcal{B}$, then there exists some $B_3 \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in B_3$ and $B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2$.

In the last part, does this necessarily refer to proper subset, or simply subset (i.e. could also have $B_3 = B_1 \cap B_2$.

$\textbf{Example}$: Let $\{a,b,c\}$ and $\{b,c\}$ be elements of $\mathcal{A}$, a basis for a topology. Since $b$ is in both sets, therefore $\mathcal{A}$ must have some third set which contains $b$ and is contained in $\{a,b,c\}\cap \{b,c\} = \{b,c\}$.

If the third set must be a proper subset, then we would have $\{b\}$, but if it can also equal the intersection we could have $\{b,c\}$ as well.

Comment: It's just a subset, not necessarily strict.

Comment: $B_3=B_1\cap B_2$ is not only fine, but even occurs quite frequently in practice. Strict inequality is not required.